# Can I reboot or reset AirPort Extreme remotely over wifi using my Mac?

Tags: network, wifi, internet, airport

Internet connection at my home (provided by the housing company) — shared to wifi via Airport Extreme — nowadays quite often cuts off. When this happens, my MacBook is still connected to the wifi just fine, but access to internet is down.

The only reliable way I’ve found to fix this is to walk over to the  Airport Extreme, disconnect its power cord & connect it again, causing it to reboot. Soon, after the wifi becomes available again, internet connection is back too.

**My question**: is there any remote or "software" way of resetting or rebooting Airport Extreme to get the internet connection back up? (For example using AirPort Utility or something on the command line on my Mac.)

[image]

If it matters: AirPort Extreme 802.11n (5th generation) running software version 7.6.9.

Comment: Before restarting your `AirPort Extreme` I suggest you to check if your connection loss is really coming from it or from your router or from your ISP. Because restarting it on every problem isn’t the right way to make it run. I had a pool of `AirPort Extreme` which stayed running for months with many users connected full time from 09:00 to 21:00.

Answer (score 2):

The AirPort Utility app has a Base Station Menu, with the option to restart.

Comment: I've edited your answer for clarity and undeleted it. One way to improve it even further would be to add screenshots which show the option.

Answer (score 1):

The "Restart..." command in the "Base Station" menu of Airport Utility exists for this reason.

Comment: The screenshot is from OS X.  And the OP says "on my Mac".  But, if you want to do it from iOS Airport Utility, then do so.  "Restart Base Station" is in the "Edit" menu.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger - I flagged the answer during review because of the wording; specifically, the phrase "at least used to have...".  Following that logic implies that at current "it no longer has."  Thusly, the answer becomes "let me tell you about a function that's no longer there" which, ultimately, doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

*From memory* there is such a function directly within one of the menus of `Airport Utility`.

Beware in case of modification of your `AirPort Extreme` configuration to be sure to be able to access it from your Mac once it will have restarted. The `AirPort Extreme` restart will take around 60 seconds.